# Gitlab using Kubernetes secret for Helm values file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my helm values file I tried to pull secret values from my Kubernetes secret file.

In normal deployment files I would do:

```
env: 
- name: PASSWORD 
  valueFrom: 
    secretKeyRef:
      name: secret-example
      key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

But I don't think this way is possible via the helm values file:

```
  password: 
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: secret-example
      key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

Previously I would set passwords using gitlabs UI to store the password. Then in the gitlab-ci build script it could just pull them in like so:

```
--set postgresq.password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

But now I store my passwords in a Kubernetes secret file. So is there a way to get this either in the helm values file, or in the gitlab-ci and pass it in like I used to do via the gitlab password method (instead of using gitlab UI)?